# What is 30th permutation of elements 1,3,5,7,9?

Tags: permutations

The answer is:  31975
But how do I get the answer with a method?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the enumeration of the permutations; the most common being

- lexicographic order, whence the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) allows one to efficiently calculate permutations from their position in the enumeration or the
- induced by the [Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter permutation enumeration](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter-Algorithmus) whose algorithmic inversion can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/223656/31310